# Is it possible to change the button CSS class state from ".ripple" to "ripple:active" by using js without manually clicking the button?

Tags: javascript, css, pseudo-class

Using JavaScript's click simulation does not work for CSS pseudo-class `:active`. After I tried some classList methods, it still doesn't work. I just wonder if there are some possible ways to realize that?

Run the snippet below and click the button to see the ripple effect. The ripple effect doesn't repeat automatically with the included `setInterval` code that simulates a click. It only works with the real click of the button:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector(`button`);

btn.addEventListener(`click`, (e) => {
  console.clear();
  // try to manually set pseudo-class `:active` ?
  btn.classList.toggle('ripple', 'ripple:active');
  console.log('classList =', e.target.className);
});

setInterval(() => {
  // js simulator click doesn't work for css pseudo-class `:active`
  btn.click();
}, 1000);
```

```css
.ripple {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ripple:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, #000 10%, transparent 10.01%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50%;
  transform: scale(10, 10);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: transform .5s, opacity 1s;
}

.ripple:active:after {
  transform: scale(0, 0);
  opacity: .2;
  transition: 0s;
}
```

```html
<button class="ripple">ripple button</button>
```

### References

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## It is impossible according to the API description so far.

The `:active` CSS pseudo-class represents an element (such as a button) that is being `activated` by the user.
When using a `mouse`, "activation" typically starts when the user presses down the primary mouse button.

### APIs

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active

https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#the-active-pseudo

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics-other.html#concept-selector-active

Answer (score -1):

You can try to recreate "active" event using js and css

CSS :

```
.ripple {
    background-color: red;
}

.ripple:active, .ripple.active {
    background-color: green;
}
```

JS :

```
let btn = document.querySelector('.ripple');

btn.addEventListener('click', e => {
    btn.classList.add('active');
    setTimeout(() => {
        btn.classList.remove('active');
    }, 500);
});


setInterval(() => {
    console.log('click');
    btn.click();
}, 2000);
```

Comment: I know that add an `.active` class solution, but it's not the solution for `:active` pseudo-class.